# Editors framework and MVP

Tags: gwt, gwt2

Is there a conflict in development or architecture that prevents me from using Editors inside the View in a GWT MVP application?

I am developing a business application and I am thinking of making Editor widgets for my beans and use RequestFactory. I will place editors inside the views when I need to display or edit single object but I will use CellWidgets when I need to display multiple objects.

Will this make a mess of my application or am i heading to the right direction?
What do you recommend according to your experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no conflict between Editors and MVP. Editors are for easy binding between view and backing beans. Using them together you can fill model via Editor framework.

Comment: In this case will the code in the workflow class in google example here  http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html be written in the View or the Presenter(Activity)? I will tell you what I am thinking : In MVP the presenter should be responsible for persistence not the View so I will need to put the driver in the presenter but in this case the presenter knows about the internals of the View and we have extra dependency created between the presenter and the editor widget which is smelly from design perspective in my POV.

Comment: I wouldn't use Editor inside presenter. I'd create POJO model that will be passed between view and presenter and create Editor for this model in view classess (e.g. you can make Java part of UIBinder pair an Editor). After driver.flush() you can pass your model to presenter and take care of it's persistence there.